# Are re-combined BTRFS incrementals identical to the original?

Tags: filesystem, backup, btrfs

I have several systems running btrfs, and I'd like to use the btrfs subvolume [send](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-send)/[receive](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-receive) features as a backup solution. I want to send daily incrementals to *remote* as efficiently as possible. That means I want to avoid sending changes in a daily incremental and later sending the same changes in a monthly incremental.

Specifically, I want to generate nightly incrementals as such:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /home /backup/volume-date-daily
btrfs send -p /backup/volume-previous-daily -f daily-date /backup/volume-date-daily
push daily-date to remote
```

After a while I'd like to combine daily incrementals into monthly incrementals without re-sending all that data from the client. If I unpack all the incrementals (`btrfs receive`), then remove all the intermediate subvolumes I don't want, is the remaining subvolume sufficient for me to unpack all future daily incrementals generated by the client?

For example, the server has dailies 1-30 from the client. I unpack them and erase all subvolumes but daily 30. When I receive daily 31 from the client, can I unpack that using `btrfs receive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of BTRFS tools 3.12 and Linux kernel 3.13, the answer is no. When serialized BTRFS data (incremental or otherwise) is deserialized (`btrfs receive`), and the intermediate volume deleted, the latter volumes are updated. When they're re-serialized (`btrfs send`) they have different IDs. Latter serialized volumes which refer back to their parent volume by ID are unable to find their parent, due to changed ID.

It's not known if there is any workaround for this behavior.

Here's what is possible:

1. Create volume snapshots on disk, serialize them where each refers to the previous snapshot, and keep all those serialized files forever.
2. Deserialize volumes to disk (`btrfs receive`), remove some intermediate volumes, and re-serialize all volumes after the deleted volumes.